# How to get all the running Chrome instances

Tags: c#, google-chrome, chromium

This is my first question here on Stackoverflow, but I've started to follow this site a quite few years ago.

I want to say that I have **already searched** really deep the web and SO about my question, but I did not succeed to solve my problem.

(I've found only how to get the window main title of the current opened tab or all the tabs, but after that I'm unable to detect *which tab belongs which instance*)

I have to deliver a program to my client that will be able to detect the idle instances of chrome and kill it.

As example: My client have **2** (**or more**) active Chrome **instances**, but he is using only the last instance, so, te remaining instances, after X milliseconds (the client has the possibility to adjust the timer as he likes) of been unfocused needs to be killed by my program.

Like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i82Ax.jpg) screenshot

I have achieved this with other programs, using GetForegroundWindow.

But the way Chrome handles the instances make my method unuseful.
I try to explain why:

If you have already an active instance of Chrome and open a new one, the main Chrome process will *embed* all the *new* instances as **tabs**, so, the user will see *two **forms*** (window) of Chrome, but in the deeps, will exists *only one* Chrome instance.

A piece of the code that I use to determine if a process window is or not focused

```
    #region [GET_THE_NAME_OF_THE_FOCUSED_WINDOW]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    public string GetActiveWindowName() {
        try {
            IntPtr HANDLE = GetForegroundWindow();

            Process[] _p = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process clsProcess in _p) {
                if (HANDLE == clsProcess.MainWindowHandle) {
                    string processName = clsProcess.ProcessName;

                    return processName;
                }
            }
        } catch { }

    return null;
    }
    #endregion
```

Exists a method to achieve what I need?

Sincerely,
Mutu Adi-Marian.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. To get an answer for your question, you must [create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), Please provide the minimal code that you have written to solve this problem and what problems are you exactly facing along with the steps you already tried to find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: In this scenario, you could add the code that achieved the effect with different programs, as described, and explain why Chrome doesn't work with this code :)

Comment: @JessedeBruijne
Hello, thank you for the response!

The problem is that when you already have an running instance of Chrome and open another one, the parent Chrome instance will "embed" the new opened instance as a tab, so, will still remain only one instance of Chrome and other child processes that are tabs

Comment: Forcefully terminating a render process is a bad idea. The browser process will think that it crashed if you do so

Comment: @Asesh
Yes, you are right, the best solution is to write an extension.